# Difference between move_uploaded_file & ftp_put

Tags: php, ftp, public-html

If i would like to upload an image for example from the client side via php script. which would be better to use as a method move_uploaded_file or ftp_put & why?
Another questions; If i would like to create a folder at the so_called public_html or www on the server but to be seen by user or at least its contents not to be seen, what shall i do?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file - only works on files uploaded via HTTP POST.
ftp_put - uploads a file to the FTP server.

Comment: what you recommend more?